# Sencha Cmd 5.0.1 with Extjs 5.0.1 issue

Tags: sencha-cmd, extjs5

I am upgrading my **Extjs** **to** **5.0.1** (from 5.0.0 ) and also **Sencha Cmd** to **5.0.1.231**

No compile time errors but on run time it is is not loading the application and giving the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined`

some other users are having the same issue..

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289872-After-update-to-5.0.1&p=1059537

Is this a bug or we are doing some thing different ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug, but I think Sencha are pushing towards using a [microloader](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/microloader.html) rather than just including the app.js file and the css ones. So my short answer is **both**! :)

Now the long one:

I was playing with setting up an ExtJS application that is to live far away from the webroot and at the same time to be available in both, development and production modes (environments).

Setting the **app.json** of the Sencha CMD app, so the **microloader.js** to load the required js and css files, proved a bit of a challenge.

My folder setup is as per below:
*(Note, my **build** folder is outside the Sencha CMD application folder - **MyApp**  - just to have the same path depth)*

```
index.cfm
/far/away/from/web/root
    ....
    /build
        /resources
        app.js
        app.json
        microloader.js
        ...
    /MyApp
        /.sencha
        /ext
        app.json
        app.js
        bootstrap.js
        ....
```

**MyApp/app.json**

```
{
    /**
     * The application's namespace.
     */
    "name": "MyApp",

    /**
     * The relative path to the appliaction's markup file (html, jsp, asp, etc.)
     *
     * Below setting seems relevant for proper loading MyApp/bootstrap.js
     */
    "indexHtmlPath": "../../../../../index.cfm",

    ......

    "output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}",
        "page": {
            /**
             * Below is relative path from the build folder to the application markup file
             */
            "path": "../../../../../index.cfm",
            "enable": false
        },
        "microloader": {
            "path": "microloader.js",
            "embed": false,
            "enable": true
        },
        "manifest": {
            "path": "app.json",
            "embed": false,
            "enable": "${app.output.microloader.enable}"
        }
    },

    /**
     * Uniquely generated id for this application, used as prefix for localStorage keys.
     * Normally you should never change this value.
     */
    "id": "f6cd3e2b-6a0c-4359-a452-e07adda808ae"
}
```

Initially, in order to use the production build, was loading directly **/far/away/from/web/root/build/app.js** file and it throw the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined
```

Now, with the **app.json** configured as per above, I can pick in my **index.cfm** whether to load:

```
for production - /far/away/from/web/root/build/microloader.js
for development - /far/away/from/web/root/MyApp/bootstrap.js
```

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers,
Pencho

Comment: Thanks for your response and detailed information. this solution does not worked for me, i even upgraded to Sencha Cmd 5.0.2.250 , still same issue. any idea ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, probably you solved this by now. If not: Do you include the produced by "sencha app build" microloader.js, but not the app.js? Can I see your "index.html" and the app.json file?

Comment: don't remember the exact solution , but it is working now, Thank you so much for your help :).appreciated!!